# Geckodriver works fine on localhost:5000 but getting error on localhost:80 , localhost,127.0.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, nginx, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to deploy a image detection system on a home built linux server . The application is running on nginx, gunicorn , python . The problem is when i run the application on localhost:5000 it works fine but getting **"Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities"** or simetime **"Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH"** when run on nginx or localhost:80, localhost , 127.0.0.1

The application usually works fine on nginx only with the geckodriver I am getting the error .....

1. ubuntu 18.04
2. python 3.6
3. selenium 3.141.0
4. firefox 76.0.1
5. geckodriver 0.26.0